# How to convert grayscale jpg to bmp with 24 bitcount

Tags: imagemagick

I have some grayscale jpeg files and I want to convert them to bmp with 24 bitcount, i.e., 3 channel. I have use imagemagick command **convert** to do it, but I just get 1 channel. I've tried those commands,

```
$ convert -channel RGB -compress None t.jpg t.bmp
$ convert -channel OOO -compress None t.jpg t.bmp
$ convert -channel RRR -compress None t.jpg t.bmp
```

but all failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-depth` option

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#depth